# Google AppMaker app not loading for users

Tags: google-app-maker

I have made a Google App Maker app based off of their PDF EMail starter and some code snippets found on this site. It works flawlessly for me in preview mode, and in its Published form.

However, when my user tries to access it (published), it does not fully load. I see the red/green circle for ~1 second and then nothing further happens. I cant figure out how to see the error in Chrome.

I have selected not to restrict access to the app, and entered my users email address as a User in Deployment options anyway. I have the Model set to be accessible to anyone.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: More details would be really helpful. Screenshots would help a ton. What is red/green circle? To see errors, right click and click inspect element. And then click on "Console".

Comment: At the time, I couldn't get a screenshot because the circle I mentioned would only flash on the screen for a fraction of a second, then the screen would be blank. So not very helpful anyway unfortunately. I realize now I could have just taken it of a working app while it was loading. But I digress.

Luckily for me, the app works just fine now. I didn't change a thing.

I appreciate you taking the time to try to help.